# Can Azure run WPF?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, azure

I'd like to write an ASP.Net MVC app running on Windows Azure that will create images using WPF.

Before I start writing it, will that work?
Does Azure have the necessary DLLs (including DirectX) and graphics power to render WPF?

(I don't have an Azure account yet, so I can't just try it)

Comment: Get a free try account: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/01/27/try-windows-azure-at-no-charge.aspx

Comment: Or here apparently without a creditcard: http://windowsazurepass.com/?campid=BB8443D6-11FC-DF11-8C5D-001F29C8E9A8

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. In particular, Azure Websites (which probably weren't around at the time the other two answers were posted) can also use WPF and I use it in my applications for

1. image processing,
2. operations on spline paths (Geometry-related stuff in WPF) and
3. pdf creation (via WPF xps creation from visual trees and subsequent conversion to a scalable pdf with pdfsharp).

It's stuff like that which makes ASP.NET such a cool platform.

The talk about GPU considerations that was raised by some people on this question is pretty irrelevant for simple image processing. I seriously doubt a GPU is even used for that when present.

Answer (score 1):

The performance in the cloud is solely dictated by how much computing power you require. Can the cloud (Azure) scale? Absolutely.

You could use an ASP.NET MVC role coupled with a Worker role which would take care of your image creation. The option also exists to [host a XBAP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425647); however there are caveats with that approach but it can be done.

Comment: I need to generate an image on the server; XBAPs won't do any good.  There won't be any difference between web roles and worker roles here; the question is basically whether DirectX works.

Comment: @SLaks Everything I have read indicates you should be offloading the GPU processing to the client. The cloud is essentially a network of VM's which obviously have no physical graphics card. Attempting to push the GPU computing effort to the VM versus using the clients readily available GPU seems a bit counterintuitive. Is there something hindering you from leveraging the client?

Comment: I need to render formatted text to an image.  You can't do that in HTML, and I don't want to require XBAPs.

Comment: @SLaks You can do it in SL; any reason to not go that route over ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely be able to do this with VM Role instances.  However, Azure nodes do not have powerful GPU's, so I'm not sure if that'll be very cost-effective?

This has been a requested feature:
http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/398032-provide-directx-and-directcompute-functionality-as?ref=comments

Comment: I don't need GPU power; I'm not doing anything complicated.  I just need it to work.

Comment: With VM role you're able to deploy whatever .DLL's you need to do the job.  Frankly, you can probably do the same with a WorkerRole and startup tasks