# What kind of graphics card are Windows Azure Virtual Machines equipped with?

Tags: azure, gpu

I am thinking about running some graphics intensive programs on Windows Azure virtual machine, but not sure what kind of hardware do they have. Does all the VM have the same GPU? What is your experience of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPUs in Azure Virtual Machine are likely to be very basic and will most probably not have anywhere near the processing power you will need for carrying out intensive graphics manipulation. To my knowledge MS don't publish the details of the graphics hardware behind their Virtual Machines (If they actually use them at all?).

There's a question here on running WPF in an Azure cloud service which may be helpful.

[Can Azure run WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899618/can-azure-run-wpf)

Comment: Why should there be any physical graphics device in the servers at all? As far as one can tell from within the VM it is just an emulated virtual device and the VM guest has no access to graphics hardware at all.

Comment: I suspect you're right. There's no listed graphics card within the VM's Device Manager.

Comment: What if someone wants to run a graphics intensive computing such as 3D rendering, it seems the cloud would not be very much usful then...:(

Comment: Doesn't 3D rendering utilise CPU rather than GPU? I assumed the GPU is used for the on-screen manipulation and then CPU handles the actual ray-tracing and rendering?

Comment: GPU can do ray tracing and much faster.

Comment: Amazon EC2 offers GPU for doing HPC tasks like molecular modeling and engineering analysis.  So in that sense there is an excellent reason for there to be a large GPU available (at least in these cases).  I suspect at some point we'll see a similar offering from Azure.

Answer (score 1):

The N series Azure VMs support beefy GPUs. The NC series VM sports Tesla K80, with DDA (discreet device assignment) it supposed to provide close to bare metal performance. NV series VMs offer Tesla M60 with nVidia GRID.

More:

- https://www.hpcwire.com/2015/09/29/microsoft-puts-gpu-boosters-on-azure-cloud/
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/12/13/n-series-azure-vms-with-gpu/

It's fascinating that there are FPGAs in Azure machines too (although not publicly accessible):
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/project-catapult/