# what kind of GPU do u get on a VM provided by AWS or Azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, gpu

On the VM I get from Azure, it has a hyper-V specific display adapter. It seems that is not OpenCL compatible, what a bummer if you have a OpenCL program to run.

Comment: You just asked this same question yesterday: [What kind of graphics card are Windows Azure Virtual Machines equipped with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001500/what-kind-of-graphics-card-are-windows-azure-virtual-machines-equipped-with)

Comment: No, this is a different question. This is asking about AWS, the other question was asking Azure

Comment: Then the tags are still wrong and the body of the question is completely useless.

Answer (score 3):

On AWS you have a [HPC offering](http://aws.amazon.com/hpc-applications/) which includes NVIDIA GPUs capable of doing CUDA and OpenCL.

The [list of instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) types contains the specs of the **Cluster GPU Instances** containing **2 x NVIDIA Tesla “Fermi” M2050 GPUs**.

You might also have a look at the [pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).